# How to use two queries to find result on the basis of first query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables `Repair_master` and `New_Equipment_info`, with the query shown here, I am able to retrieve all the latest date record of maint. by grouping RID and fill the data grid.

```
SELECT 
  t1.RID
 ,t1.RDATE
 ,t1.EQ_ID
 ,new_equipment_info.Equipment_Name
 ,new_equipment_info.Complete_specification
 ,t1.DEPT
 ,t1.REPAIR_MAINT
 ,t1.ACTION_TAKEN
 ,t1.SAPRES
 ,t1.ATT_BY
 ,t1.[STATUS]
 ,t1.RNO
FROM
  Equipment.dbo.REPAIR_MASTER t1 
INNER JOIN
  Equipment.dbo.new_EQUIPMENT_INFO 
    ON t1.EQ_ID = New_Equipment_info.Equipment_Id 
INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      Eq_ID
     ,max(RDate) as MaxDate 
    FROM 
      Equipment.dbo.REPAIR_MASTER 
    group by 
      Eq_ID
  ) tm 
    ON t1.EQ_ID = tm.EQ_ID 
        and t1.RDATE = tm.MaxDate
WHERE 
  t1.Repair_Maint = 'maint.' 
ORDER BY 
  t1.RDATE DESC
```

But I want to know the number of days from the last date filtered from query and current date.

Like this

```
DATEDIFF(day,  MaxDate, GETDATE()) AS Difference)
```

Kindly advise

Further I want to enter number of days in text box and click button and show only those records having a difference greater than the value entered.

```
private void btnOverDue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            string p = "SELECT t1.[RID],t1.[RDATE],t1.[EQ_ID],new_equipment_info.Equipment_Name,new_equipment_info.Complete_specification," +
              "t1.[DEPT],t1.[REPAIR_MAINT],t1.[ACTION_TAKEN],t1.[SAPRES],t1.[ATT_BY],t1.[STATUS],t1.[RNO]FROM([Equipment].[dbo].[REPAIR_MASTER] t1 inner join[Equipment].[dbo].new_EQUIPMENT_INFO ON " +
              "t1.EQ_ID = New_Equipment_info.Equipment_Id inner join (select Eq_ID, max(RDate) as MaxDate FROM [Equipment].[dbo].[REPAIR_MASTER] group by Eq_ID) tm on t1.EQ_ID=tm.EQ_ID and t1.RDATE =tm.MaxDate)" +
              "where t1.Repair_Maint='maint.' ORDER BY t1.RDATE desc";  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(p, con);
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(p, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Repair_master");
            EquipGrid.DataSource = ds;
            EquipGrid.DataMember = "Repair_master";
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you are asking how to pass a parameter to the query?

Comment: Is there a reason adding `DATEDIFF(DAY,  tm.MaxDate, GETDATE()) AS Difference` to the query wouldn't work?

Comment: not necessary i just want to calculate the overdue of maint from last date..

Comment: Are you wanting this latest max date to be included in the data source of the DataGrid, or have it in a variable in C# to use elsewhere?